# upload a update built with xamarin (mono touch ) to an existing application built with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, app-store

I have a application on app store which was earlier built with xcode.But now we are developing apps using xamarin .
Now i want to add an update to the same existing version built with xamarin .Is that possible or should i upload it as a new application .please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Just use the same bundle/app id.